# How to make VOLTE/LTE or LTE calls using Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-nano, shields, ethernet-shield

I want to make VOLTE/LTE calls using Arduino. I searched everywhere in Google. At last I found a website [LTE Cellular Shield for Arduino with Voice!](https://www.hackster.io/botletics/lte-cellular-shield-for-arduino-with-voice-3da59b).

But I cannot find SIM7500 Shield in online shops. So U want to use SIM7000. But I can't find code for it. Can you share any?

Comment: have you seen this? ... https://github.com/botletics/SIM7500-LTE-Shield?files=1

Comment: See but I can't understand anything

Comment: I want the code what I give

Comment: I connect SIM7500 to Arduino Uno. and connect speaker mic etc.Okk. Then I have to give a code to Arduino by arduino ide, right. I want this code which I give

Comment: now i understand ... you want the code that you load into the Arduino ... the link in my comment above has example code ... you can find it in the README.md

Comment: Code is not available on README.md

Comment: yes it is ...click on `step-by-step wiki` ... your internet search skills need some sharpening ... lol